# Importing NodeJs into TypeScript compiling errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to import a nodejs class into the typescript code using a declaration (d.ts) file.
To test it I created a simple nodejs class, declaration file and the typescript file that is going to import (consume) the nodejs class.

contents of TS_PROJECT/node_modules/newtest/index.js:

```
var HelloWorld = function() {

}

HelloWorld.hello2 = function() {
  console.log("hello2");
}

HelloWorld.prototype.hello1 = function() {
  console.log("hello1");
}

module.exports = HelloWorld;
```

So as you can see, it's a class that will have a member function "hello1" and a static function "hello2".

Now i'm trying to declare it in TS_PROJECT/newtest/index.d.ts:

```
declare module newtest {
    export class HelloWorld {
        hello1():void;
        static hello2():void;
    }
}
export = newtest;
```

And eventually trying to consume it from index.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./newtest/index.d.ts" />
import * as mymodule from "newtest";
```

Now I'm trying to instantiate the object and call the functions but no matter what i try it doesn't compile. I tried lots of variations, but none of them works. For example this:

```
    // Doesn't Work 
    import HelloWorld = mymodule.HelloWorld;
    let s: HelloWorld = new HelloWorld();
    // It results with the following compile errors:
    // error TS2339: Property 'HelloWorld' does not exist on type 'typeof "newtest"'.
    // error TS2694: Namespace '"newtest"' has no exported member 'HelloWorld'.
```

I won't list all the rest of my variations. But i would appreciate if anybody could help me with proper declaration and instantiation of the object.

Thank you!

Comment: We're gonna need some error messages to even begin to figure out what's going on

Comment: Ok, i added the error messages in the post. But i will simplify the question. What would be the proper way to make a declaration for the HelloWorld class and instantiate it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `import` the type, since you're already importing everything from the module and naming it `mymodule`. You can do a couple things:

1. Import the class directly:

   ```
   import { HelloWorld } from 'newtest'
   let s:HelloWorld = new HelloWorld();
   ```
2. Access the type from the imported module:

   ```
   import * as mymodule from 'newtest';
   let s:mymodule.HelloWorld = new mymodule.HelloWorld();
   ```
3. Create a local variable reference to the type:

   ```
   import * as mymodule from 'newtest';
   const HelloWorld = mymodule.HelloWorld;
   let s = new HelloWorld();
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this results in the same errors: Compilation error: error TS2305: Module '"newtest"' has no exported member 'HelloWorld'. And then if you still run the code: [1] var s = new newtest_1.HelloWorld();
[1]         ^
[1] 
[1] TypeError: newtest_1.HelloWorld is not a constructor

Comment: I think my declaration is incorrect. Apparently it's not exported properly

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using? I actually wasn't able to reproduce this using the current version 2.1.5

Comment: My version is 2.1.5 too. I posted an answer to my issue. Now i'm curious how come that it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured the answer. In my example the declaration module "newtest" represents the exported nodejs object. Since the exported object is already HelloWorld object, it's wrong to define inside another class HelloObject. 
So the simplest solution would be to have a nodejs code like:

```
    var HelloWorld = function () {

    }

    HelloWorld.hello2 = function () {
      console.log("hello2");
    }

    HelloWorld.prototype.hello1 = function () {
      console.log("hello1");
    }

    // Only this part changed
    module.exports.HelloWorld = HelloWorld;
```

This way we are exporting an object that has HelloWorld class inside. That fixed the compilation and the compiled JS.

Also another issue that I had, in the declaration file "newtest" has to be in quotes. Only that way it attaches the module to the nodejs package.

These to fixes solved my problem. But the question is still remains. What if I still have to use "module.exports = HelloWorld;"? How should I declare this module in this case?

Comment: I think in that case `export default HelloWorld;` would be what you want